# Is there a way to keep original URL in AMP Stories?

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

Our business has decided to use AMP stories, and they want their stories to keep the original URL. I know its possible in AMP page, but can it be done on AMP stories as well?

The URL should be
`https://www.example.com/amp/stories/xyz` instead of
`https://www-example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/www.example.com/amp/storie/xyz`

Would appreciate a little help here.

Comment: an `amp-story` is an HTML page reachable at a specific URL. What's the question again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should work just like regular AMP pages, using Signed Exchanges.

It's a one click thing if you use CloudFlare: https://blog.amp.dev/category/signed-exchanges/

Or you can implement Signed Exchanges by yourself: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/signed-exchange/